# Can’ t change a @State var with a func in a struct

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

So I’ve had this problem where I would like to use a @State var to control the opacity of a certain element. However it seems I can’t change this value after just calling a method on my struct in another place. Is there a better way to do this? I’ve also tried changing the Circle().opacity (I kept a var for Circle then) instead of just changing the value but didn’t work.

```
struct Picker : View {
    private let circleSize : CGFloat = 100.0
    private let off_const : CGFloat = -(100.0/2) + 15.0
    @State private var opacityValue : Double = 0.0
    var body : some View {
        Circle()
            .size(width: circleSize, height: circleSize)
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
            .offset(x: off_const, y: off_const)
            .opacity(opacityValue)
    }
    
    func changeOpacity(){
        self.opacityValue = 0.5
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling the function? From outside of `Picker`, and how?

Comment: Structs are value type and they don't have an identity. So, if you created a variable for your `Picker` view elsewhere, then you changed the opacity parameter of some variable, but not the same as what's actually used in the rendered view. And in any case, this wouldn't have worked, since the views are immutable. What you'd want to do is pass this opacity value as an init parameter, or as a property of an @EnvironmentObject or an @ObservedObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code it seems that you don't call your function as @George_E said.

By adding OnTapGesture you change opacity by tapping on circle.

```
    Circle()
    .onTapGesture {
            self.changeOpacity()
        }
```

If you want to change opacity from another View you need to add `@Binding` to your Picker. Then you can init your picker with that binding and change opacity from outside.

Change your `@State` var to `@Binding` var in your Picker

```
@Binding var opacityValue: Double
```

Then you create `@State` var in View where you init your Picker, also you need to transfer and call your function somewhere. As example in `.onTapGesture`.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var opacity: Double = 1.0
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(opacityValue: $opacity)
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.changeOpacity()
        }
    }
    func changeOpacity(){
        self.opacity = 0.5
    }
}
```

Another option is `@EnvironmentObject` or an `@ObservedObject` as @New Dev said. That's a little more complicated, but I'm sure your can find solution here on StackOverflow. Hope that helped..